# Overloading " >> " Crashed the program

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Rupee{
    private:
        int number;
        int number2;
        int number3;
    public:
    Rupee()
    {

    }

    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &os, const Rupee &e );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &is, const Rupee &e );
};


    ostream& operator << (ostream & os ,const Rupee &e)
    {

        os<<endl << e.number << endl;
        os << e.number2<< endl;
        os << e.number3<< endl;
        return os;
    }

    istream& operator >> (istream & is ,const Rupee &e)
    {

        is>>e.number>>e.number2>>e.number3;
        return is;
    }



int main()
{
    Rupee o1;

    cin >> o1;
    cout << o1;
}
```

Hello There,
I am trying to make an overloaded the operator  `<<` . When Im running the program the program does not run for `" << "` but works fine for `" >> "`.
Where am I doing wrong? Am i using the correct istream and ostream classes for the overloaded functions?

Comment: How did your compiler manage to compile the implementation of your extraction operator: It should have thrown an error in: `istream& operator >> (istream & is ,const Rupee &e)` function...

Comment: This code simply cannot compile.

Comment: it is not doing it . wheres the problem?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved, then, quickly, hurry, delete the compiler and every associated file it came with. Use a newer compiler. BTW, Which compiler is that? and what version?

Comment: the compile problem is passing a const & to the >> operator. It needs to set the values so it cannot be a const

Comment: @DietmarKuhl its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile problem noted from the commentors is from passing a const reference to the >> operator. Values are being read into the variable, so making it const causes a compiler error, the const keyword should be removed:

```
friend istream &operator >> (istream &is, Rupee &e);

istream& operator >> (istream & is, Rupee &e)
```

After making these changes the program compiles and runs fine for me, visual studio 2015 here. You might want to pause the program on exit to read the output however:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

Comment: Oh.. Let me try that too.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved Please, learn the difference between compile-time and run-time error from this post, and the fact that compile-time error messages are easily accessible and they are for humans to read and think about. No sane compiler outputs *"Your code doesn't work."*.

Comment: Yeah I do know the differences, The thing is when I was running the code on my compiler I had a bit of more stuff there. However when I pasted it here, i removed the unrelated part and was unaware of the fact that It wont even run now.